# Python compile time error when using GeoJson

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used the below code and it gives an error. Here's my code:

```
fg_population.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'),
style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor':'green' if x['properties']['POP2005'] < 10000000
else 'orange' if 10000000 <= x['properties']['POP2005'] < 20000000 else 'red'}))
```

Then I get the following error messages:

`ValueError: Unhandled object <_io.TextIOWrapper name='world.json' mode='r' encoding='utf-8-sig'>`

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace. It's not clear where the error comes from otherwise. Also, I'd recommend splitting the style_function into a separate `def` rather than a lambda - it's rather hard to look at the code as it is now.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the docs](https://folium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#geojson-topojson-overlays), you shouldn't use the `data=` to open the file. Furthermore, some formatting and splitting things up would help:

```
the_world = open('world.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
the_style = lambda x: {'fillColor':
                           'green' if x['properties']['POP2005'] < 10000000
                      else 'orange' if 10000000 <= x['properties']['POP2005'] < 20000000
                      else 'red'}
the_map = folium.GeoJson(the_world, style_function=the_style)
fg_population.add_child(the_map)
```